# Onvif : GetService() method is removed in latest dependency for Android

Tags: android, rtsp, ip-camera, onvif

`getService()` method is removed from gradle dependency of Onvif which is available in library module for the same in Android platform.

Have used Onvif library for getting RTSP streamig url from IP camera and make successfully called below method calls:

```
getServices()

onDeviceInformation()
```

but not able to make third method call `getProfiles()`.

getting this error in Logcat.

```
E/ERROR: request failed: GetProfiles 
     Response: 500 - Internal Server Error
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:tan="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl" xmlns:tst="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/storage/wsdl" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error" xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:tmd="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http" xmlns:d="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:wsadis="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:wsrf-bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wsntw="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2" xmlns:wsrf-rw="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/rw-2" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsrf-r="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2" xmlns:trc="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/recording/wsdl" xmlns:tse="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/search/wsdl" xmlns:trp="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/replay/wsdl" xmlns:tnshik="http://www.hikvision.com/2011/event/topics" xmlns:hikwsd="http://www.onvifext.com/onvif/ext/ver10/wsdl" xmlns:hikxsd="http://www.onvifext.com/onvif/ext/ver10/schema" xmlns:tas="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/advancedsecurity/wsdl"><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
    <env:Subcode><env:Value>ter:ActionNotSupported</env:Value>
    <env:Subcode><env:Value>ter:InvalidOperation</env:Value>
    </env:Subcode>
    </env:Subcode>
    </env:Code>
    <env:Reason><env:Text xml:lang="en">Optional Action Not Implemented</env:Text>
    </env:Reason>
    </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think that you should at least point to the library that you are using...

Comment: I have not getting ur point , have mentioned that have used Onvif Library module instead of dependency for the same.